# Typescript how do I extend an interface which uses a generic type?

Tags: typescript

I have this interface structure set up:

```
export interface Response<T> {
  hasMoreResults: boolean
  pageToken: string | null
  status: string
  result: T
}

export interface ArrayResponse<T> {
  hasMoreResults: boolean
  pageToken: string | null
  status: string
  result: T[]
}
```

As there are many shared fields I want to write something like this instead:

```
interface ArrayResponse extends Response<T>{
    result: T[]
}
```

However this throws an error I cannot fix. Is there a straightforward way of changing the type of the property which uses the generic in both cases? I don't want to do `T | T[]` as the result in one interface, as this will cause problems in my code. Thanks.

Comment: In your case, why don't use `interface ArrayResponse<T> extends Response<T[]> {}` ?

Comment: This gives me cannot find name 'T' unfortunately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your code the only difference between `ArrayResponse` and `Response` is that `result` is an array.

You could use:

```
export interface Response<T> {
  hasMoreResults: boolean
  pageToken: string | null
  status: string
  result: T
}

export type ArrayResponse<T> = Response<T[]>
```

As `Response` can already take any type as an argument.

Comment: Thanks I think this is the cleanest solution

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can [omit](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittk) it like this

```
export interface ArrayResponse<T> extends Omit<Response<T>, "result"> {
  result: T[]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, `ArrayResponse` is just an instantiation of `Response` where `T` is an array. If we want to define `ArrayResponse` to just pass in the item type we could do this:

```
export interface Response<T> {
  hasMoreResults: boolean
  pageToken: string | null
  status: string
  result: T
}

export interface ArrayResponse<T> extends Response<T[]>  {
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=10&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgJWAGdIkjgAeAFQD44BvAKDjgAtMiBZaYQogVwA2MIgC44AIwgRBwTEmZwwmAObAqEANbAk4ojCjIVcAD5wkQwYv2YY-MXH2GkKxVGJCY4qowC+jRlBIWEQUNCxcOABBKChMAE8+UnJqOlBUJAATIgJiZMoqAG0AXToGP0YgA)